# c# textbox text to solid value

Tags: c#, textbox

I need to create a string/int which will contain a text from texbox. It must be stable, this string/int can't be changed after editing this textbox.
Any solution?
Blocking textbox or something like that:

```
string x = textBox1.Text;
```

do not satisfy me

edit;
i got this:
string x = textBox1.Text;
so this every time will be receive value from textBox1, and the value of the textbox can be changed

Comment: what do you mean -- can't be changed?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it must be stable", and "blocking the textbox". Do you just want the textbox `disabled`?

Comment: Can you give some more information about your problem?

Comment: i got this:
string x = textBox1.Text;
so this every time will be receive value from textBox1, and the value of the textbox can be changed

Comment: Once you make the assignment, the value of the variable is independent from the value of the Text property of the textbox. The string data type is immutable, so you are safe: altering the contents of the textbox after assignment won't change the value of your variable. You don't need to do anything to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here if you want to have a variable that always contains the current text in the textbox.

The first option is to just...not, and always use `textbox1.Text` any time you want to access the text, instead of using a variable in its place.

The next option would be to create a property.  It would potentially make the syntax a bit nicer without really changing anything:

```
private string MyText
{
    get
    {
        return textbox1.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        textbox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `MyText` instead of `textbox1.Text`.  It won't really change anything, but it will potentially shorten the syntax.

A final option would be to have a string that you update when the textbox text changes:

```
private string myText;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textbox1.TextChanged += (_, args) => myText = textbox1.Text;
}
```

While this is probably technically the closest to what you've asked, it's also something I wouldn't suggest doing.  It just wouldn't gain you anything over using a property, and setting the value of that string wouldn't set the value of the textbox.

Comment: I think he means just the opposite: how to prevent updates from happening. See my comment to the OP. Just guessing.

Comment: @CesarGon He has made statements that both imply he wants this, and that he wants the opposite.  Since the code that he already has does the opposite, I assume it isn't what he wants.  If it is what he wants, then he already has that code.  Either way, with the addition of this answer he now has both solutions instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want, so here is my guess:

You don't want the `TextBox` to be editable ...

the `TextBox` has two Properties that can help you with that:

`Enabled` and `ReadOnly`

if you set `Enabled` to false, the `TextBox` will be grayed out, and the user will no longer be able to change the text.

if you set `ReadOnly` to true, the TextBox will not be grayed out, but the user will not be able to change the text.

Comment: His edit says, `"and the value of the textbox can be changed"` when this was suggested in comments, so it doesn't seem to be what he wants.

Comment: @Servy and a bit earlier he wrote "Any solution? Blocking textbox or something like that"... so i guessed that the still changable textbox was his problem ... but it would not be the first time if i was totally wrong ;) ... the question is anything but clear